# add a function to a 3rd-party closure in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, scope, closures

Ok, I wouldn't think to do this in C#, but javascript is designed with much more flexibility in access.

there's a plugin like this

```
(function($)
{
    ...more stuff
    var results={a:1,b:2}  //this I need to modify
    var someData={x:1}
    send = function(){
        //send results ajax
    };

    if(typeof beforeSend=='function')
        beforeSend(someData) //hook to use results
})(jQuery)
```

So, in my own code, I have the function `window.beforeSend = function(d){}`

and it does have the someData which is in the scope I need to modify. But here's the question:
How can I **modify** the **results** var that's within the closure before it sends it.
I need to add

```
window.beforeSend = function(d){
    window.quantumTunnelThroughScope.results['c']=1
}
```

The reason I need to do this is because I cannot modify the code of the plugin.  Of course if I add the beforeSend within the closure, it works, but then I'm modifying the library which I'm not allowed to do in this case.

I've seen some awesome eval('this.xx' =function ) etc etc but I can't make it work.

**EDIT:** I clarified that actually it's a different var in the same scope that needs to be edited

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well because I need to add c=1 to results before it sends them

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, I apologize, I reduced the code down to it's essence but messed up by passing the wrong variable in the example

Comment: is beforeSend(someData) a function which is originally present in the plugin?

Comment: @JeroenVervaeke yes, just as it shows there.  it's already there, and while it doesn't provide access to the scope, it does run "before" the results are sent so it just happens to be a good place to insert the code to modify the results var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no *reasonable* way for `beforeSend` to reach into that closure and modify `results`. `results` in the code presented is entirely private to code within that closure.

The *unreasonable* way to *try* to do it is to decompile and recompile the plugin function, via `eval`, and insert a call to a function before the `beforeSend` that lets us modify `results`:

```js
(function($) {
  $.run = function() {
    // You mentioned "ajax," so let's make this
    // asynchronous
    setTimeout(function() {
      var results = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
      };
      var someData = { // Need to modify this
        x: 1
      };
      send = function() {
        //send results ajax
      };

      if (typeof beforeSend == 'function') {
        beforeSend(someData); //hook to use results
      }

      console.log("in plugin, results = ", results);
    }, 10);
  };
})(jQuery)

window.modifyResults = function(d) {
  return ["new", "results"];
};
window.beforeSend = function(r) {
  r.c = 1;
};

jQuery.run = (function() {
  // Function#toString, on nearly all browsers, returns the source
  // code of he function (or something near to it) except on functions
  // implemented in native code. We take that string and replace
  // the "beforeSend(someData);" call with two calls, the first of
  // which lets us modify the `results` variable. Then we use eval
  // to turn that back into a function, and assign the result to
  // where the plugin put its function originally.
  return eval("(" + jQuery.run.toString().replace(
    "beforeSend(someData);",
    "results = modifyResults(results); beforeSend(someData);"
  ) + ")");
})();

jQuery.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But may or may not work, depending on how the plugin is written, as it lifts it out of its original scope and recompiles it in the scope of our function updating `jQuery.run`.

I think I'd prefer to take the hit of modifying the plugin. :-)

---

Note: In the above, I've used a "static" jQuery function. If the plugin you're replacing provides an *instance* function, the kind you can call on jQuery instances, e.g. the `bar` in `$(".foo").bar()`, you'll find it on `jQuery.fn` instead of `jQuery`:

```
jQuery.fn.pluginFunction = eval(...);
```

Comment: I'm apologize it's not clear, but by "before" I'm just referring to the beforeSend hook that gets run before the actual send function.  That beforeSend hook is actually in the code of the closure and gets called already before the send, so in my own code, if I put the magic scope modifying code in that hook function, it WILL run before the send

Comment: Also, I feel like since I can see the object if I browse the jquery object, I should be able to access it somehow in code.

Comment: Also, if I could inject my function into the scope itself, then of course it would have access to the variable

Comment: @AwokeKnowing: I've added an *unreasonable* way that may work. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. I appreciate your evaluation of which is better, and that's exactly what I wanted to be able to evaluate before deciding the course of action.  I'll see if this works in this instance.  I also wanted to bring my javascript power to the next level for those extreme cases and my general understanding.